# Prediction interval for multi step forecast

Tags: forecasting, prediction-interval

If I have a multi-step forecast of some time series, where the model is some auto-regressive function
$$y_t=f(y_{t-1},x_{1t},x_{2t})$$

is it a valid approach to use sections of historical data to train the model and than evaluate it on future section recursively to obtain the multi-step forecast. Doing this multiple times with different sections of my historical data I can obtain the forecast error
$$e_t=\hat{y}_t-y_t$$

over the forecast horizon T.
Can I use this error to estimate the prediction interval?

Thanks!

Comment: What are these sections? Why are you doing this? What is the goal?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. The sections are sections of 60 days of historical data of the timeseries. I than make a forecast using the data from this section. Then I move the whole section, re-train the predictor and make another forecast.

Comment: Are you referring to CV for time series? See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/

Comment: Yes but with constant training set length

Comment: I don't know why you would do that. Why would you limit your training data like that?